# Get date value of every days of current month

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this:

```py
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
days = [datetime.date(year, month, day) for day in range(1, num_days + 1)]  # return all the days of the current month
```

And it's return every days like this:

```py
[datetime.date(2021, 8, 1),
datetime.date(2021, 8, 2), 
datetime.date(2021, 8, 3), 
.
.
.
datetime.date(2021, 8, 26), 
datetime.date(2021, 8, 27), 
datetime.date(2021, 8, 28), 
datetime.date(2021, 8, 29), 
datetime.date(2021, 8, 30), 
datetime.date(2021, 8, 31)]
```

How can i get that days in normal format.

For example: **2021-08-01**

Comment: To be clear, you want the string representations of those dates formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import calendar
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
days = [datetime.date(year, month, day).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for day in range(1, num_days + 1)] 
print(days)
```

Use strftime function to convert datetime object to string in specified format

Answer (score 1):

Convert your datetime objects to `str` (as "YYYY-MM-DD" is the default format) or use [`.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime):

```
import calendar, datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
num_days = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]
days = [
    str(datetime.date(year, month, day)) for day in range(1, num_days + 1)
]  # return all the days of the current month
print(days)
```

Out:

```
['2021-08-01', '2021-08-02', '2021-08-03', '2021-08-04', '2021-08-05', '2021-08-06', '2021-08-07', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-09', '2021-08-10', '2021-08-11', '2021-08-12', '2021-08-13', '2021-08-14', '2021-08-15', '2021-08-16', '2021-08-17', '2021-08-18', '2021-08-19', '2021-08-20', '2021-08-21', '2021-08-22', '2021-08-23', '2021-08-24', '2021-08-25', '2021-08-26', '2021-08-27', '2021-08-28', '2021-08-29', '2021-08-30', '2021-08-31']
```